# PostgreSQL Date is one day off with my Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, react-native, express

I am working on a React Native App with Expo that is connected to a PostgresDB.

I have a query that loads some Data in between two dates it looks like this:

```
db.query(
      `SELECT activitydate, phaseid, time, userid, remark, zkub, status, hours_status.color status_color, comment, project.name project_name
      FROM hours 
      LEFT JOIN phase ON phase.id = hours.phaseid
      LEFT JOIN project ON project.id = phase.projectid 
      LEFT JOIN hours_status ON hours_status.statusid = hours.status
      WHERE activitydate >= '${startDate}' AND activityDate <= '${endDate}'
      AND userid = '${userid}' ORDER BY activitydate`

... startDate is 2019-08-01 and endDate is 2019-08-31 in this example !
```

It does give me back the data I need(example):

```
{"activitydate":"2019-07-31T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":766x7,"time":180,"userid":1xx,"remark":"I did this and that","zkub":" ","status":0,"status_color":"000000","comment":"","project_name":"coolProject"}
... of course this is 1 Element from the Array !
```

Now the problem is that the activitydate should be : "2019-08-01" but it is "2019-07-31" even though it is safed correctly inside the db with the correct activitydate.

Its not only wrong when I get the data in the browser with a localhost/api/... but it's also displayed wrong inside my app.

I think it might have something to do with the Timestamp that is set? it is set to `T22:00:00.000Z` as you can see. I dont know which date the browser or nodejs(express) might be using but it puts the results 1 day behind.

Comment: what you have stored in activitydate in db ???

Comment: I stored a date. It has the type date and inside the db it looks like this: 2019-08-01 and if I query it looks like above.

Comment: This is mostly happening when you are converting from UTC to a system specific time zone. Did you try converting taking into consideration the output timezone as well ?

Comment: Yes I considered it - but the query on its own not running in my app just in my backend should give me correct dates -- is there a way that I can tell the query/nodejs/ or something else to use UTC or to also use T22:00:00.000Z at the end or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get records between two dates then use

```
WHERE activitydate between `${startDate}` and `${endDate}`
```

also make sure you are passing your date in right format like  `YYYY-MM-DD`

using moment we can format our date in required format

```
 moment(our_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')  // npm install moment --save
```

So, when you get your result then pass your result activitydate to moment it will return date in  YYYY-MM-DD format

Try to use format(datee,'dd - MM - yyyy') function like

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(activitydate, "%Y-%m-%d") // try instead of activitydate
```

Comment: I also tried this Query version with between it give me exactly the same data back. And yes I am already using MomentJS inside my app and formating it correctly. thats why it is weird and I think it has something to do with  the T22:00:00.000Z

Comment: have you tried.when you are getting your date activitydate then pass it to moment(activitydate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: you can also set your timezone using moment-timezone in your app

Comment: Ok I see your point but now imagin I am just entering: localhost/api/startdate/enddate/userid and getting JSON array back in the browser without considering my app. Then it should give me back the array with correct values for the activitydate because it is stored correctly on the db but its 1 day off - is there somethiing that can be set in the query or on the express server that could append T22:00:00.000Z or something? Do you get what I mean :D

Comment: If you could find a solution it would be insane - but I already appreciate your effort!

Comment: try to use DATE_FORMAT in your query

Comment: Ok thanks - that might be helpfull Im gonna try around with this. Do you maybe now how to tell DATE_FORMAT to look like this: 2019-08-01T22:00:00.000Z so to format it to just append T22:00:00.000Z ?

Comment: Ok I will check it out but I just found a to_chat function where I could append T22:00:00.000Z at the end of the date - I will test things out - Again much thanks for your time dude!

Comment: It really seems to work correctly now - again much thanks to you dude keep up the great work! Have a good day!

Comment: same to you dude :)